# Android error timeout json service logcat

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, logcat

When attempting to run the application in the emulator I get the following error in the "logcat". I assume that the error is in some of the following lines of code.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?

> 10-11 05:23:40.667 2392-7446/com.alvardev.demos.limacultural
>   D/com.alvardev.demos.limacultural.http.RestJsonService: Iniciando
>   servicio
>
> 10-11 05:23:40.667 2392-7446/com.alvardev.demos.limacultural
>   D/com.alvardev.demos.limacultural.http.RestJsonService: Llamada a la
>   url http://localhost/culturapp/registrar.php
>
> 10-11 05:23:40.687 2392-7446/com.alvardev.demos.limacultural
>   D/com.alvardev.demos.limacultural.http.RestJsonService: Llamada con
>   datos
>   {"register":{"email":"carlos@outlook.com","name":"carlos","password":"123"}}
>
> 10-11 05:23:40.687 2392-7446/com.alvardev.demos.limacultural
>   D/com.alvardev.demos.limacultural.http.RestJsonService: Llamada metodo
>   2
>
> 10-11 05:23:40.687 2392-7446/com.alvardev.demos.limacultural
>   D/com.alvardev.demos.limacultural.http.RestJsonService: Llamada
>   tipoaccion 6
>
> 10-11 05:23:40.687 2392-7446/com.alvardev.demos.limacultural
>   D/com.alvardev.demos.limacultural.http.RestJsonService: Llamada POST
>
> 10-11 05:23:40.687 2392-7446/com.alvardev.demos.limacultural
>   D/com.alvardev.demos.limacultural.http.RestJsonService: antes por el
>   post
>
> 10-11 05:23:40.687 2392-7446/com.alvardev.demos.limacultural
>   D/com.alvardev.demos.limacultural.http.RestJsonService: text/json
>
> 10-11 05:23:41.067 2392-7446/com.alvardev.demos.limacultural
>   E/com.alvardev.demos.limacultural.http.RestJsonService: Error timeout
>
> 10-11 05:23:41.077 2392-7446/com.alvardev.demos.limacultural
>   E/com.alvardev.demos.limacultural.http.RestJsonService: Connection to
>   http://localhost refused
>
> 10-11 05:23:41.097 2392-7446/com.alvardev.demos.limacultural
>   D/com.alvardev.demos.limacultural.http.RestJsonService: Respuesta
>   codigo : 1000
>
> 10-11 05:23:41.097 2392-7446/com.alvardev.demos.limacultural
>   D/com.alvardev.demos.limacultural.http.RestJsonService: Respuesta data
>   : null 10-11 05:23:41.157 2392-2392/com.alvardev.demos.limacultural
>   E/HttpClient: TIME OUT

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    Log.d(TAG, "Iniciando servicio");
    String url = null;
    String datos = null;
    int metodo = 0;
    int tipoAccion = 0;
    HttpResult resultado = null;

    Bundle parametros = intent.getExtras();

    url = parametros.getString(LLAVE_URL);
    datos = parametros.getString(LLAVE_CONTENIDO_PETICION);
    metodo = parametros.getInt(LLAVE_METODO_PETICION);
    tipoAccion = parametros.getInt(LLAVE_TIPO_ACCION);

    Log.d(TAG, "Llamada a la url " + url);
    Log.d(TAG, "Llamada con datos " + datos);
    Log.d(TAG, "Llamada metodo " + metodo);
    Log.d(TAG, "Llamada tipoaccion " + tipoAccion);

    ResultReceiver recibidor = parametros.getParcelable(LLAVE_RECIBIDOR);

    HttpMethod metodoEnum = HttpMethod.forValue(metodo);
    Log.d(TAG, "Llamada " + metodoEnum.toString());
    switch (metodoEnum) {

    case POST:
        Log.d(TAG, "antes del post");
        resultado = postJson(datos, url);
        break;

    case GET:
        resultado = getJson(url);
        break;

    default:
        break;

    }

    Log.d(TAG, "Respuesta codigo : " + resultado.getStatusCode());
    Log.d(TAG, "Respuesta data : " + resultado.getData());
    Bundle datosResultado = new Bundle();
    datosResultado
            .putString(LLAVE_CONTENIDO_RESPUESTA, resultado.getData());
    datosResultado.putInt(LLAVE_TIPO_ACCION, tipoAccion);

    recibidor.send(resultado.getStatusCode(), datosResultado);
    //recibidor = null;
}


private HttpResult postJson(String bodyRequest, String url) {

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 30000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 30000);
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

    String data = null;
    int status = 0;

    StringEntity se;
    try {
        se = new StringEntity(bodyRequest, "UTF8");
        se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/json"));
        Log.d(TAG, "text/json");
        httpPost.setEntity(se);

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String respuesta = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        data = respuesta;

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        status = HttpCode.ERROR.getCode();
        Log.e(TAG, "Error protocolo");
        Log.e(TAG, getErrorMessage(e, "Error al realizar la peticion"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error timeout");
        Log.e(TAG, getErrorMessage(e, "Timeout sucedio"));
        status = HttpCode.TIMEOUT.getCode();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error general");

        Log.e(TAG,
                getErrorMessage(e,
                        "Error generico sucedio al realizar la peticion"));
        status = HttpCode.ERROR.getCode();
    }

    return new HttpResult(data, status);
}
```

Comment: please rewrite your question in **english**. ***por favor, volver a escribir su pregunta en Inglés***

Comment: The Connection to http://localhost is refused. So stupid question but did you replace the "localhost" in the URL with the ip address of your pc, Server or whatever. I assume it's not the device which is running the app.

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you.